# Mysql get latest article by user and total number of articles?

Tags: mysql

Cant seem to figure out how to get the latest article posted by user, and total number of articles by that user..

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.role, COUNT(articles.id) AS 
       total_articles, (SELECT articles.title 
       FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS latest_article_title
FROM users
JOIN articles ON users.id = articles.author_id
```

I have the following tables:

```
users (id, username, password, role) 
articles (title, body,created_at, author_id)
```

I am just learning MYSQL, so any help with this would be well appreciated!

Edit:
Been reading your answers, and wanted to do my own query, that I understand and write myself, so I came up with this:

```
SELECT users.username, COUNT(articles.id) AS total_articles, 
       (SELECT articles.title FROM articles WHERE articles.author_id = users.id 
           ORDER BY articles.id DESC LIMIT 1) as latest_article_title
FROM users
LEFT JOIN articles ON users.id = articles.author_id
GROUP BY articles.author_id
```

Is that okay? I mean, it works, and gives me exactly the results I need. But, is  "nested" select, inside of select okay to use?

Comment: Plz show the table structure and your expected output

Comment: Select sub query is not good practice. It Takes to much time to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get latest article id and total number of articles which posted by user by using this query

```
SELECT articles.author_id, 
                         Count(articles.id) AS total_articles, 
                         Max(id)            latest_article_id 
                  FROM   articles 
                  GROUP  BY articles.author_id
```

Then, join this data with *user* and *articles* table to get expected result

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.username, 
       u.role, 
       a.total_articles, 
       b.title AS latest_article_title 
FROM   users u 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT articles.author_id, 
                         Count(articles.id) AS total_articles, 
                         Max(id)            latest_article_id 
                  FROM   articles 
                  GROUP  BY articles.author_id) a 
              ON u.id = a.author_id 
       LEFT JOIN articles b ON a.latest_article_id = b.id
```

Comment: Heyo.. Thanks for the response. Can you look at my edit on top?  Is it okay If I nest SELECT inside of SELECT like that? Would that query be okay to use? Wanted to write my own query, to se if I could, and it works..Cheers!

Comment: Hi @miqro, I've looked your edit. The nested selects will be slowed down your query. For small amount of data, it's ok. But for a great amount of data, it has a very bad performance. For better performance, you should use JOIN.

Comment: But you also used SELECT inside SELECT in above example? "LEFT JOIN (SELECT articles.author_id,...", is that one different?

Comment: Yes, it's different between using SELECT inside SELECT and SELECT in FROM statement. Basically, when you use a nested SELECT inside SELECT, a nested SELECT will be executed per each result row. While SELECT in FROM statement will be only executed 1 time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. one more quick question.. When you do 'FROM users u', does that give 'users' a shorter name, or does it do anything else?

Comment: Yes, it's just an alias for shorter name

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact table structure so there could be a mistake in the query but i would try something like this:

```
 Select user.id, user.username, users.role, COUNT(articles.id) as total_articles, 
        (Select articles.title 
        from articles 
        Where author_id=user.id 
        order by articles.created_at desc Limit 1) as latest_article_title
from users
join articles ON user.id = articles.author_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT t.*,COUNT(articles.id) AS total_articles
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.title,a.id AS article_id,a.`author_id`,users.id AS user_id, 
           users.username, users.role
    FROM articles AS a
    INNER JOIN users ON a.author_id = users.id
    ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 1
) t
INNER JOIN articles ON articles.`author_id` = t.author_id
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can try below sqls. I have implemented all and givings steps to get final answer.

Tables

User

```
id  username    password    role
1   mamta        123456 admin
2   hema         124378  user
```

Articles

```
title   body            created_at  author_id
Poem    This is a poem  2017-06-01     1
Story   This is a Story 2017-06-20     1
Song    This is a Song  2017-06-10     2
Sangeet This is a Sangeet 2017-06-08    1
Rhyme   This is a Rhyme 2017-06-16      2
```

Step 1

```
SELECT MAX( created_at ) AS created_at, COUNT( author_id ) AS Total
FROM  `articles` 
GROUP BY author_id
```

Output

```
created_at  Total
2017-06-20  3
2017-06-16  2
```

Step 2

```
SELECT ar1.*,ar2.total FROM articles ar1
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT MAX( created_at ) AS created_at, COUNT( author_id ) AS total
FROM  `articles` 
GROUP BY author_id
) ar2 
ON ar1.created_at = ar2.created_at
```

Output

```
title   body              created_at    author_id   total
Story   This is a Story   2017-06-20    1            3
Rhyme   This is a Rhyme   2017-06-16    2            2
```

Step 3 (Final Sql)

```
SELECT u.id,u.username,u.role,ar.title ,ar.total AS total , ar.created_at FROM user u
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT ar1.*,ar2.total FROM articles ar1
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT MAX( created_at ) AS created_at, COUNT( author_id ) AS total
FROM  `articles` 
GROUP BY author_id
) ar2 
ON ar1.created_at = ar2.created_at
) ar ON ar.author_id = u.id
```

Output

```
id  username    role    title   total   created_at
1   mamta      admin    Story   3       2017-06-20
2   hema       user     Rhyme   2       2017-06-16
```

Comment: Heyo.. Thanks for the response. Can you look at my edit on top?  Is it okay If I nest SELECT inside of SELECT like that? Would that query be okay to use? Wanted to write my own query, to se if I could, and it works..Cheers!